# Change background opacity onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background opacity of the body `onclick` inside a function which shows and hides a menu. Similar to a the effect you have with a modal box. I'm trying to do this using `document.getElementsByTagName("body")`, but doesn't seem to change it.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "0.5";
}

$('body').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('a b');
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testDiv">
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/88zero/pen/qYZxaE

Comment: the code in that codepen doesn't match your post

Comment: I edited the post, thanks

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "0.5";`

Comment: This would do the trick but notice that by doing so, you are making the whole body translucent.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an HTMLCollection not a single element. You can't set the style on a collection. The error console is throwing an error because of this.

Comment: A better way to do this would be `document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use body tag for backdrop but use a div instead:

HTML

```
<div id="testDiv">
...
</div>
<div id="backdrop"></div>
```

CSS

```
.sidenav {
    ...
    z-index: 2;
}
...
#backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JS

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I can't seem to get the backdrop div to get the opacity effect onclick? I put the code in here: https://codepen.io/88zero/pen/mLPKzB

Comment: in function openNav() you typed document.getElementsById("backdrop") but it should be getElementById (without "s")

Answer (score 2):

You can use just

```
document.body.style.opacity = 1;
```

without using `getElementsByTagName("body")`.

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the opacity of the menu not the body of the page? The effect I need is the same as this site when you click menu: https://www.puregym.com/

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` will return an array of elements. In the body case will return only one. But you still need to target it directly.

You can use the next code:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

This way you target that first object that was selected. Now, i dont think you want to do this. You might need to have a `main` div on the right side and change the opacity on that. This so you can fake a modal.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")` returns an Array, you have to choose the first index of it.

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqdEBM

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the opacity of the menu not the body of the page? The effect I need is the same as this site when you click menu: puregym.com

Comment: @cryptographic Actually it is changing the opacity of the body. But since your menu is inside your body, so the opacity of the menu also changes. So rather than setting the opacity of the whole body, set opacity only for it's **background**

Comment: I advice that you use a separate div as a backdrop that appears/disappears depending on whether or not your sidebar is showing. Another answer talks about this, you can refer to them. ;)

Comment: Try doing `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"`, where the first 3 values are *rgb* values and the last is the *opacity* value